# sudo access in android terminal emulator on android emulator (development)

Tags: android, terminal, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obtain root access via su on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator)

Hi,

I'm working on an Android App in Eclipse with the Andoid Eclipse Plug-In. I'm saving files on the virtual devise and would like to have a look at them in the Terminal Emulator (Dev Tools => Terminal Emulator). However I can't access certain directories and am refused a sudo access. How could I get a sudo access?

I'm running an Android 2.3 Emulator

Thanks for your help/hint!

Comment: I reply to this question here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not a direct answer, but you do have access to root via adb shell.

The su in the emulator is uid locked to root, so only root can run it (which you get automatically via adb shell)