# Scripting in android

Tags: android, command-line, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a script. Say suppose new.sh.It contains

```
su
cd /data/dalvik-cache/
ls
```

but i am unable to run the script in my emulator which starts with eclipse project . Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank u,
Sindhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply run 'su' on the emulator, there's no root access by default.  You'll need to install the 'su' program as well as the SuperUser.apk, and you'll have to do this each time you start the emulator unless using snapshots.

More information and links to the files you need can be found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator) as well as [this blog posting by Russell Davis](http://russelldavis.blogspot.com/2011/01/rooting-android-emulator.html)

Comment: Ok, so what have you done and what didn't work when you did it?

Comment: Show us your exact cmds, and exact error messages. Good luck.

Comment: My script consists of the above commands only. i.e. 1.su  2.cd data/dalvik-cache/ 3. ls. I installed superuser.apk and bin files in my emulator. and  followed this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator.

Comment: I did not get though i tried all these ways. So kindly help me