# How would I go about running a shell command upon toggling a checkbox in Android

Tags: java, android, shell, command, root

Basically I have an app where the end-user has a choice of several (8 to be exact) checkboxes to toggle. These checkboxes are supposed to run different root commands, and another root command as they untoggle (to reset their selected choice.) However, I am not diverse enough to figure out how I would go about doing this. And thus the title for this question: How would I go about running a shell command upon toggling a checkbox in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html

Also see this other SO post: [Run shell commands from android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449515/run-shell-commands-from-android-program)