# android dumpsys permission denial

Tags: android, shell, dump

I have an application where I create a process and call the `dumpsys telephony.registry` command to get information about the mobile network status.

```
String[] cmds={"dumpsys telephony.registry"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds [0]+"\n");
```

and then after that I parse the result of the command. For `"ls"` or other commands it works fine. For dupmsys I get `Permission Denial: can't dump telephony.registry from pid-953, uid=10090`. I get the same error results for `dumpsys power` or other dumpsys commands.

I have set DUMP permissions `android.permission.DUMP` in the android Manifest like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201659/android-adb-shell-dumpsys-tool)

I think that I am doing this right since Android offers this feature [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DUMP)

I have also done the step described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app) to force eclipse to allow me to give my application DUMP permission in the manifest.

When I execute the dumpsys command I always get the same result

`Permission Denial: can't dump telephony.registry from pid-953, uid=10090`

Am I doing something wrong? Why does android OS still deny me access to the dump service ?

PS I have set min API 8 and I am testing the application on device running (ICS)
API 15

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does android OS still deny me access to the dump service ?

Because that permission is flagged as `android:protectionLevel="signature|system|development"` (or `signatureOrSystem` using the old syntax) on Android 2.3+, and therefore cannot be held by ordinary Android SDK applications.

Comment: I thought that the permission in the android manifest was there to give developers this option.Is there a way for me to do it ? Or Android will not allow me to dumpsys no matter what ?

Comment: @malcolmthe4: "Is there a way for me to do it ?" -- root your device and install your app on the system partition.

Comment: I have tried to run su before the dumpsys commnad. I know that it works, but this restricts me only on rooted devices.... Is there not another way? I read this https://gist.github.com/vnu/3258553
How can I sign my application with a platform key ?

Comment: @malcolmthe4: "How can I sign my application with a platform key ?" -- compile your own ROM mod and install that ROM mod on your own device. The signing key you used for compiling the firmware in that ROM mod would be the signing key you would need to use to sign your app, for it to qualify for `signature`-level permissions.

Comment: OK! so dumpsys is only possible for su and for custom roms.
I will try to implement the functionality I want without dumpsys.
Thanks anyway!!! :)

Answer (score 6):

There's another (hacky) way to access `dumpsys` without rooting your device - through *adb shell*.

This will require allowing USB debugging, and finding the port of the adb service.

1. Enable USB debugging on your device. This option is found under `Settings` -> `Developer Options`.
2. Connect your device to a PC, and run the following command from the PC's shell/command line:
   `adb tcpip 12345`. Then, from your devices shell, issue the command `adb connect localhost:12345` from your application. You can now disconnect the device from USB.
   Alternatively, you can scan the ports on your device one by one without USB connection, using `adb connect localhost:<portnum>` and find the port adb service is listening to.
3. Authorize USB debugging from the pop up confirmation dialog, if prompted. Check the "always" checkbox to do not require this step again.
4. Now, when you have access to the adb service, use `adb shell dumpsys ...` from your application code to get whatever service dump you need.

NOTE: You don't need the `DUMP` permission for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

The android dev team decided to stop granting these permissions to third-party apps. Only system apps can now get them.

more details:https://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=100

Answer (score 1):

It reports private values of core Android services that you would never be able to typically obtain.  [Official document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DUMP) says "Not for use by third-party applications".

Answer (score -2):

Add permission on your manifest "android.permission.DUMP". I have not tried it yet but it shows on adb shell that it is missing that permission

Comment: This doesn't work!