# Display contents of a Directory Android

Tags: android

I am trying to display the contents of /data/dalvik-cache through the following program but it returns a NULL pointer exception. After a bit googling i found out that i don't have permissions to read the contents of /data folder.My phone is rooted and is there a way to display the contents of all such folders whose permissions are limited?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File listfiles[] = null;
        final String s = "/data/dalvik-cache";

        File aDirectory = new File("/mnt");

        if(aDirectory.isDirectory())
            listfiles = aDirectory.listFiles();

        for(int i=0;i<listfiles.length;i++)
            Log.i("FileName", listfiles[i].getName());

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run shell or other program via `su` command (e.g. with root privileges). You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator).

Answer (score 1):

I work on directory picker code. To list a **dir** content use:

```
File f = new File("/cashe");
String[] d = f.list();
```

Result is *null*. 
Other **dir** it work fine.