# android root emulator? Running application on sdcard

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there root emulator for android where I could actually use su to execute a file?

I'm trying to run Emerald on my android phone but when I try to run ./ec (for compiling .nm files for emerald) but I get Permission Denied.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this stackoverflow post. Its about your problem,and a user answered with a solution for the use of sudo commands on Android emulator. Here the link: [Obtain root access via su on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator)