# Howto root android emulator running Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, root

I am trying to get root access to the Android Emulator which comes with the Android SDK running Android 7.0. 
I tried these instructions:
[Obtain root access via su on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator)

But I get:

```
E:\Develop\AndroidSDK\platform-tools>adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts
```

I also followed the instructions at the end of this thread: [How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)

But I get:

```
E:\Develop\AndroidSDK\platform-tools>adb root
E:\Develop\AndroidSDK\platform-tools>adb remount
Not running as root. Try "adb root" first
```

obviously "adb root" does not give me root access.

Help is very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're on the Google Play system image (`system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86`).  If so, adbd is set to secure in ramdisk.img.  I was able to work around it by swapping out the ramdisk.img with the one from the non-Play image (`system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86`).